# Measure Theory - Lebesgue Integral over non- $\sigma$-finite spaces

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

In most courses on Measure Theory the Lebesgue Integral is introduced initially for simple functions on finite spaces, then for general functions on finite spaces and finally for general functions on  $\sigma$-finite spaces.

I was wondering if there exists any sort of notion of integrals on non- $\sigma$-finite spaces? If not why so? Is it because there's no way to handle the convergence of non-countable sequences, and we would essentially need to redefine the notion of integrability altogether?

Would appreciate any insight on the matter.

Thanks!

Comment: Your experience doesn't match mine at all. I've usually seen the Lebesgue integral defined over an arbitrary measure space from the start.

Comment: I think the issue with measures that are not $\sigma$-finite is that Tonelli's and Fubini's Theorem don't necessarily hold.