# Is sigma-finiteness required for the Change of Variables theorem?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I came across the following statement in Lehmann & Romano's *Testing Statistical Hypotheses*:

> **Lemma 2.3.2** Let $T:(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{A})\to(\mathcal{T},\mathcal{B})$
> be a measurable transformation, $\mu$ a $\sigma$-finite measure
> over $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{A})$, and $g:(\mathcal{T},\mathcal{B})\to(\mathbb{R},\mathfrak{B}(\mathbb{R}))$
> a real-valued measurable function. If $\mu^{*}$ is the measure defined
> over $(\mathcal{T},\mathcal{B})$ by
> $$
> \mu^{\ast}(B)=\mu[T^{-1}(B)],\quad\forall B\in\mathcal{B},
> $$
> then
> $$
> \int_{T^{-1}(B)}g\circ T\,\mathrm{d}\mu=\int_{B}g\,\mathrm{d}\mu^{\ast},\quad\forall B\in\mathcal{B},
> $$
> in the sense that if either integral exists, so does the other and
> the two are equal.

**Can we make the same statement without requiring $\mu$ to be $\sigma$-finite?** And why not?

Instead of providing a complete proof, the authors suggest to go through the standard generalisation procedures from simple to non-negative to real-values measurable functions. Other texts I have access to either state $\sigma$-finiteness as a standing assumption or define Lebesgue integration for the Borel-Lebesgue measure only (which is  $\sigma$-finite). I couldn't see where I would rely on $\sigma$-finiteness in my transition from simple to general measurable functions. To be honest, neither could I find where $\sigma$-finiteness is used in the Lebesgue integral definition, and other people seem to suffer from the same lack of clarity, judging from these unanswered questions:

- [Can the Lesbegue integral be defined on a space which is not $\sigma$-finite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2474420)
- [Measure Theory - Lebesgue Integral over non- $\sigma$-finite spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742147)

I know that $\sigma$-finiteness is necessary for the existence of the Radon-Nikodym derivative, and counter-example are known and discussed here:

- https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258936/radon-nikodym-theorem-for-non-sigma-finite-measures
- [Is $\sigma$-finiteness unnecessary for Radon Nikodym theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1760977/is-sigma-finiteness-unnecessary-for-radon-nikodym-theorem)

I am looking for a similar example for the above statement or an
explanation of the exact role of $\sigma$-finiteness in the
change-of-variables lemma.

Hints and suggestions are appreciated, but nothing is better than a complete answer!

Comment: $\sigma$-finiteness is redundant for this abstract change of variables theorem.

Comment: The change of variable in your Lemma does not require $\sigma$-finiteness. The push forward $\nu(f^{-1}(\cdot))$ works only because presages behave well under complementation, and unions (and intersections).

Comment: ... meant to say preimages.